# What is the syntax of a string compare in a value expression

Tags: ios, core-data-migration

I am trying to migrate a simple core data model using a mapping mode.

I have added a BOOL field, which will be true if another field has certain specific string values.

The value expression for that BOOL field that should do the trick is $source.stringName == "Specific string value".

XCode however complains about "$source.stringName == "Specific string value" == 1" having a bad syntax: Unable to parse the format string

So I add parenteses:  ($source.stringName == "Specific string value").

XCode keeps complaining, now about "($source.stringName == "Specific string value") == 1" having a bad syntax.
So, what is the correct syntax to test a string value against an entity field?

Comment: If my Answer was helpful to you then you should mark it as Accepted. It will increase your Accept-rate as well as helpful for future visitors also. :)

Answer (score 0):

You you want to compare `BOOL` to `NSString`  then convert you string value in to `BOOL` 
such like,

```
BOOl isBoolValue= [myStringValue boolValue];
```

And then compare 2 `BOOL` value such like ,

```
if(firtBoolValue == isBoolValue)
{
  //  compare;
}
else
{
  // not compare;
}
```

If you want to `NSString` Comparison then

First you need to convert `BOOL` to `NSString`, such like

```
NSString *stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myBoolValue ? @"YES" : @"NO"];
```

Then after put condition like,

```
if([myFirstString isEqualToString:stringValue])
{
  // compre
}
else
{
  // not compre 
}
```

Comment: It is not a problem in Objective-C code but in setting up a Core Data Mapping model.